# How do I tell if await is running or has finished running when closing wpf window

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am running async await pattern.
Why the thread is running the variable that equals the await is still null until it finishes I have found.
I thought it would be a task,
For example there is a class variable defined as

```
IXPubMagickServiceCompareOutputModel _results = null;
```

It is the variable that equals the to the await in an async method

```
 _results = await CompareImageServiceAsync(inputModel, progress,
                       PrintImagesAsyncCommand.CancellationTokenSource.Token)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When this line of could and the await thread is running  a window closing even is handled.
In this event handle the `_results` variable is null while the await thread is still running.
Why is that?
I thought I could cast the `_results` to the corresponding task as

```
var resultsTask = (Task<IXPubMagickServiceCompareOutputModel>)_results;
```

But I can not because the `_result` variable is still null while the await task is running

Comment: Call `PrintImagesAsyncCommand.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` in your `OnClosing` event-handler.

Comment: `await` doesn't run, it *awaits* an already active task to complete without blocking, and returns the result if any. The very code you posted `IXPubMagickServiceCompareOutputModel _results` shows that `_results` is *not* a task at all, it's a `IXPubMagickServiceCompareOutputModel` value.

Comment: Your post would profit from some editing.

Comment: The task in this case is the one returned by `CompareImageServiceAsync()`.

Comment: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to use `CancellationToken`.

Like so:

```
class MyWpfWindow // or MVVM ViewModel
{
    protected override void OnClosing()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = this.PrintImagesAsyncCommand.CancellationTokenSource; // Create a local reference copy to avoid race-conditions.
        if( cts != null ) cts.Cancel();
    }

    private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        IXPubMagickServiceCompareOutputModel results;
        try
        {
            CancellationToken ct = this.PrintImagesAsyncCommand.CancellationTokenSource.Token;
            results = await this.CompareImageServiceAsync( inputModel, progress, ct );
            // Don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in WPF UI code!
        }
        catch( OperationCanceledException )
        {
            // The `OnClosing` event was invoked while `CompareImageServiceAsync` was running, so just return immediately and don't let the `OperationCanceledException` escape.
            return;
        }

        // (Do stuff with `results` here)
    }
}
```